# How to handle different device sizes

Tags: android, opengl-es

I know how to handle screen sizes, but it is quite a different matter when using OpenGL ES. The thing is that normally I would just get the size of the screen in pixels and using the numbers given I would align items to be displayed.

But, as I mentioned before, in OpenGL ES it is quite different. I want to draw a simple grid on the screen, but I want all the squares on all the devices to be the same size. That means that with bigger screens I would have more columns and rows instead of bigger squares. So the real question is how to convert screen size in pixels into OpenGL vertex system.

Comment: May be introducing the width height of the screen in the grid size calculation can help.

Comment: Actually, this itself is quite simple, the problem is to draw it using opengl es vertex system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was very stupid when asking this. After a bit of experimenting it turned out that the size of the squares of the grid will stay of the same size, because of the way opengl es vertices work. On bigger devices is the size the same as on smaller ones, because the scale stays the same, only the corner indices change accordingly.